# FoxPro -> MySQL

Tags: mysql, foxpro

I'm building a website for a client that uses a FoxPro desktop database system.

The data that should be shared between the database and website is essentially a list of members (fairly flat structure: their contact details, a few flag fields etc)

They'd like any changes that are made to these member details to be automatically synched through to the website (mysql database). It doesn't need to be totally instant but the process needs to be easy.

My question is what are the simplest approaches that could be used here? they are willing to compromise a bit to save development time/cost.

Is there an easy way for FoxPro could talk directly to my online MySQL database?

Could FoxPro create an XML or CSV type file and pass it to a web script? (which i then parse and update MySQL with)

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Hasn't FoxPro acquired ODBC connectivity yet?

Comment: Erm, kinda.  You can do a connect with a DSN.

Answer (score 2):

You could use either ODBC or OLE DB from Visual FoxPro.  Using ODBC is typically fairly straightforward.

- Use [SQLConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0esyccz6.aspx) or [SQLStringConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07y5fbfz.aspx) to connect to the server.
- Some [connection string examples](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql#p29) show what might work for the SQLStringConnect call.
- Then call [SQLExec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1x933c7s.aspx) to run some queries.

Comment: @gio, I agree with Mark, just create your website directly querying and updating against the VFP database via OleDB connections...

Comment: @DRapp, Sometimes the website is hosted on a non-Windows box...which makes ODBC an interesting affair.

Answer (score 0):

Foxpro has an intrinsic function CURSORTOXML, which will take a table and convert it to XML
It is fairly well documented in the help files, but here is a simple example of its use

```
LOCAl lcXML,lnRecords

use my_table

lnRecords=CURSORTOXML('my_table','lcXML',0)

? lnRecords
? lcXML
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML for sending information to web application by HTTP REQUEST.
to create/read XML in foxpro, you can use CURSORTOXML/XMLTOCURSOR.

In your web application, you can create a web service to receive/send XML data.

If you want another data type, you can use JSON data. Use QDFOXJSON   https://qdfoxjson.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Create a Shared Folder on your Web Server.
2. Create a CSV of your Data and save on the Shared Folder.
3. Create a Cron Jobs/ Scheduler to parse and dump the data to your Mysql.

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Get the odbc driver from here:  https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/

You may also need Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86) vcredist_x86.exe

Use this code to establish the mysql connection

```
PUBLIC server,port,db,uid,pw
server="" & use mysql ip
port="" & port mysql is open on
db="" & db name
uid="" & user anme
pw="" & password

mysql = SQLSTRINGCONNECT('Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};Server=' + server + ';Port=' + port + ';Database=' + db + ';uid=' + uid + ';Pwd=' + pw + ';',.T.)
IF VARTYPE(mysql) == 'L' OR m.mysql < 0
    MESSAGEBOX('MySQL Connection Failed. Logging will be disabled for this session.',16,'MySQL Error',3500)
ENDIF
```

Here's an example to do an insert into a mysql table.  I use it for logging user actions into mysql.

```
IF VARTYPE(mysql) != 'L' AND m.mysql >= 0
    SQLPREPARE (;
        m.mysql;
        ,'INSERT INTO logging (computer,operator,application,program,version,action) VALUES (;
            ?COMPUTERNAME ;
            ,?OPERATOR ;
            ,?thisApplication ;
            ,?thisProgram ;
            ,?thisVersion ;
            ,?logMessage;
            );';
        )
    SQLEXEC(m.mysql)
ENDIF
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd say your quickest/easiest bet is probably to do the following via a nightly script:

1. [export your FoxPro data to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbbwtcbh%28v=VS.80%29.aspx#foconconvertingbetweenxmlvisualfoxprodataanchor3)
2. push the data into the MySQL database using something like Python or Java

In the long run though, you're probably better off totally ditching FoxPro after the initial import ;)

Comment: Thanks, the dataset isn't huge so I wonder if it could even happen on a button press from the database (client is keen on this). I develop in PHP so as long as it can get the XML or even a CSV sent to a .php script I can update the DB easily from that.

Comment: Maybe send your XML from the FoxPro app via an HTTP POST request to your server? On the server side, you'd connect to the db and import the XML using PHP.

Comment: On the subject of ditching his FoxPro desktop application, very easy to say that of course but you might find that it works perfectly well and does everything the customer wants, like all the COBOL application out there, to cite another example. No sense in ditching platforms for the hell of it.